# Multi-level Association in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a medical application.  In it, I have associations between users and clients (obviously), and an association between users and treatments, and users and settings (for a settings table).

But the tricky part here is that the client also has to be associated to the treatments table, because they are the ones that have the treatments on their record.  The user is simply the one administrating all of the above.  And also we have patients who are associated to clients, so it will need to be multi-layered.  So owners have clients who also have patients.  And patients have treatments as do Clients and do owners.

It seems really complex to me and I am having a hard time getting anything beyond user working.  I am using the basic relationship setup in Rails (i know very little about rails).  I am using @treatment.user = current_user on the create method, and then simply associating the tables needed  with a user_id.  I put a client_id on the treatment table, but that won't work will it?

Do I need a polymorphic association (not sure what that is though)?  OR do I need seperate tables to do all of this matching?

Thanks.

Code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules.  Others available are:   
# :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,   
# :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

# Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model  
attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation,
                :remember_me, :role

  validates :email, presence: true
  has_many :clients
  has_many :settings
  has_many :treatments

  ROLES = %w[admin receptionist practitioner]

  def role_symbols
    [role.to_sym]
  end

  def to_s
    email
  end

end
```

Comment: could you provide more information on the association between all the models? A user (the one who inputs data into the system?) has many clients (doctors?) and many treatments (why?). Every client has many patients, every patient has one(?) client? How do owners factor in? I tried drawing a UML class diagramm, but couldn't. Could you pleas provide one?

Comment: Definitely need to provide the object model. There's no way to get this right without one.

Comment: Also, why do Users need an association to Treatments if they are just the ones running the system?

Comment: @vpsz - Because the client owns an account and the User has to manage that account, so the Users need an association to the client and patient, not exactly the Treatment, but they will have a second degree association.

Comment: @vpsz has a very valid point. That model seems to be off. IMHO the user should be associated to the client (which has an owner). The client in turn should have patients, which have treatments. But then again: I don't know the details of your software

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not totally sure yet, on what your problem is. 
But since you mentioned you are not familiar with Rails, this might help you:

Have a look at the [`has_many :through relation`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) (also available as `has_one :through`)

So you could probably do something like this:

```
# patient.rb
class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :treatments, :through => :client
end
```

Comment: Wow yeah this looks exactly like what I need.

Comment: @Dain Glad I could help. I appreciate getting an upvote and a mark for "best answer", though :-)

Comment: Sorry about that, there ya go.  Still sort of new around here :)